# Call a control event handler with multiple controls

Tags: vb.net, events, controls, handler

```
Private Sub NullValidation(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FirstNameTextBox.Validating,
             LastNameTextBox.Validating, FatherNameTextBox.Validating, 
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sender.Text) Then
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(sender, "Text box is empty ")
    End If
End Sub
```

I want to check my controls validation out of this event handler (in a button click handler). But as it requires sender and e arguments it won't works. How can I do it?

Because number of controls are more than what I have wrote here(more than just FirstNameTextBox and LastNameTextBox), it doesn't seem a good solution to write a validation code for every one of them. But as it requires sender and e arguments it won't works. How can I do it?

Comment: To make this a good question you need tell us what isn't working and what error you get.

Comment: grouping them together like that makes sense at first, but only if **all* you are checking is if they are empty.  as soon as you have to test an email or phone or zip code address format etc, you will have code breaking out those controls for special testing and then your procedure bloats horrendously.

Answer (score 3):

First thing you should do is to set [option strict on](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx). You're not using the correct method signature. The [validating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.110).aspx) event is defined as:

```
Public Delegate Sub CancelEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CancelEventArgs)
```

Change the type of `e` from `EventArgs` to `CancelEventArgs`. You may need to import the namespace `System.ComponentModel`. Then set `e.Cancel` to `True` to indicate that the validation didn't pass.

```
Private Sub NullValidation(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles FirstNameTextBox.Validating, LastNameTextBox.Validating, FatherNameTextBox.Validating
    Dim ctl As Control = TryCast(sender, Control)
    If ((Not ctl Is Nothing) AndAlso String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ctl.Text)) Then
        e.Cancel = True
        Me.ErrorProvider1.SetError(ctl, "Text box is empty ")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for option strict alone ... i think `(ctl IsNot Nothing)` is much more readable esp for a novice (or native english speaker)

Comment: Thanks @Plutonix! Yup, it's way more readable when using `()`.

Comment: What do "Not ctl Is Nothing" do? whatever this doesn't solve the main problem. I want to recheck validation when I click on the submit button. there are a lot of controls on the form and validating them again doesn't seem very wise.

Comment: @n3verLieMe when you click on a Text control the default syntax for  the `TextChanged` event is created, not `Validating` - they have different event signatures as mr Kringsja describes

Comment: @n3verLieMe There's no way (unless you've changed the settings) that you have option strict on. If so `sender.Text` will give you a *"late binding"* error.

Comment: @n3verLieMe  there is a remote possibility that `TryCast` will fail and therefore return nothing, so `(ctl IsNot Nothing)` tests for that condition. with Option Strict, you must convert `Sender as object` to `Control` to work with `Control` properties (like Text)

Comment: No. there is no error and when I change signature with what you said I get this error " Private Sub NullValidation(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)' has multiple definitions with identical signatures.

Comment: that just means you already have a proper `Validating` event defined elsewhere - just delete the empty one

Comment: @n3verLieMe You have two (or more) methods named `NullValidation`. Rename or remove.

Comment: it (signature) works fine with one control but it shows above error when I use it with multiple controls

Comment: Thanks a lot Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå. it worked. but main problem still exist

Comment: Your main problem? This *was* your main problem.

Comment: just check the question again and you will understand. There's the semantic problem rather than just a syntactic one